# Xamarin / XCode UIWebView Resize Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, resize, xamarin

I am creating a mobile app that  will load a webpage in one of its screens, but for some reason the webpage always resizes itself out of the webview bound. Please see below screenshots and advise. I am not sure what I did wrong since I am very new in mobile app development. I tried to google for similar problems and wasnt able to find anything similar, so I apologize in advanced if this is a repeating question. Below is a copy of my ViewDidLoad.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        webViewGoogle = new UIWebView (View.Bounds);
        View.AddSubviews (webViewGoogle);

        string url = "http://google.com";
        webViewGoogle.LoadRequest (new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl(url)));
        webViewGoogle.ScalesPageToFit = true;
    }
```

Below is a screenshot of my design. I only want to put the website INSIDE the UIWebView box, but it resizes to cover the full screen..(second screenshot) Please help!
edit: fixed the issue by changing viewDidLoad() with the following:

```
 public override void ViewDidLoad ()
 {
    string url = "http://google.com";
    webViewGoogle.LoadRequest (new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl(url)));
    webViewGoogle.ScalesPageToFit = true;
 }
```

Taking out the subView did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
webViewGoogle = new UIWebView (View.Bounds);
```

tells iOS to make the webview as big as the bounds of the view that contains it.  If you want the webview to be smaller, specify a smaller frame when you instantiate it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed my view to
webViewGoogle = new UIWebView (webViewGoogle.Bounds);
and this is the view I got. Please see a new image in original post and advise.

Comment: You need to define a new RectangleF with the appropriate dimensions (relative to the parent view) and use that for the frame of your webview.